# maintain checked checkbox state event in jquery,ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox, state

I have checkboxes and submit button. User can filter the options using checkboxes and  button click. But now i want to maintain the state event for this checkboxes. So user should know whick checkboxes are already checked and again they can filter the options from checkboxes.Upto now i am successfully able to filter the options using checkboxe and button click but not getting logic how to maintain the state event of checked checkboxes.So after page refresh user should be able identify the checked checkboxes event.I am storing the checked checkboxes in database as an array and later retrieving it.
Here is my code:
js code:

```
        function getFahrzeuge() { 
        var opts = [];
        $("#FAHRZEUGE input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
            {
            opts.push($(this).attr("id"));
            }

        }); 
        return opts;
    } 

        function saveFahrzeugeWidget(opts){

    if(opts.length == 0) return false;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
        data: {'filterOpts' :opts, 'aktion' : 'save-widget-vehicle'},
      success: function(data){
         getFahrzeugeWidget();
         //$('#fahrzeuge').html(data['html']);        
      },
      error: function(data){
            alert('error');         
            }
    });
  }


  function getFahrzeugeWidget(opts){
    if(!opts || !opts.length){
      opts = allFahrzeuge;
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      //data: {filterOpts:opts, 'aktion' : 'get-widget-vehicle','timestamp': new Date().getTime()},
      data: {filterOpts:opts, 'aktion' : 'get-widget-vehicle'},
      success: function(data){            
       $('#FAHRZEUGE').html(data.html);
      },
      error: function(data){
            alert('error');         
            }             
    });
  }  


  $('#FAHRZEUGE .butt-rahmen').live('click', function(){
        var opts = getFahrzeuge();              
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'saveId')
        {
                saveFahrzeugeWidget(opts); 
                if($('#FAHRZEUGE input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length <=0) {
                            alert('überprüfen Sie bitte atleast ein fahrzeuge');
                            getFahrzeugeWidgetEdit(opts);
                     } 
        }                   

        });         

 var allFahrzeuge = [];
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    allFahrzeuge.push($(this)[0].id)
  })
```

dashboard.php

```
 if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle-edit')
    {
        $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
            0   => array( 'FAHRZEUGE','enabled',$page['script'],''),
            1   => array( 'EDIT-FAHRZEUGE','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),  
        );

        $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-fahrzeuge']).'</div>
                        '.CreateMessage().'
                        <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">
                            <table id="FAHRZEUGE" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" checked />
                                    <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl Fahrzeuge ohne Bilder</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" id="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" value="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" checked />
                                    <label for="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis">Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis</label><br>

                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" id="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" value="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" checked />
                                    <label for="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern">Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="Herausforderungen" id="Herausforderungen" value="Herausforderungen" checked />
                                    <label for="Herausforderungen">Herausforderungen</label><br><br>                

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                            </table>
                            '.CreateButton($page['button']).'
                        </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>';

        $return = array(
            'status' => 1,
            'html'  => $html
        );

        echo json_encode($return);
        die();
    }



     if($param['aktion'] == 'save-widget-vehicle')
      {     
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        if (isset ($param['filterOpts']) && is_array ($param['filterOpts']) )
        {
        // save it into the session
       $_SESSION['filterOpts'] = $_POST['filterOpts'];
        }   
      }


        $opts = !empty($param['filterOpts']) ? $param['filterOpts'] : array();
      $tmp = array();
      foreach ($opts as $opt) {
            $tmp[] = $opt;          
      }   
        $query ="UPDATE dashboard_widget_users w SET w.configuration=\"".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($tmp))."\" WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =".$user_id." AND w.dsnr_dashboard_widget=1";           
      $result = mysql_query($query, $myConnection);   
                $return = array(

        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => ''
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();  
}


if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle')
{
    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
        1   => array( 'FAHRZEUGE','aktiv',$page['script'],''),
        0   => array( 'EDIT-FAHRZEUGE','enabled',$page['script'],'',''),    
    );        

            /*when empty default config...
            $query=    "SELECT dashboard_widget.configuration FROM dashboard_widget WHERE Id =1"; 
            */ 

           $query ="SELECT dashboard_widget_users.configuration
                                         FROM dashboard_widget_users
                                         INNER JOIN yw_user ON dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_yw_user = yw_user.intern
                                         INNER JOIN dashboard_widget ON dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget = dashboard_widget.id
                                         WHERE dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_yw_user=".$user_id." AND dashboard_widget.id=1 ";  
                    $result = mysql_query($query, $myConnection);


        $linksVehicleWidget = array();
        $configVehicleWidget['Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder'] = array(
            'link' => 'fahrzeuge.php?parameter=1',
            'image' => 'news/bild1.jpg',
            'linkName' => 'Fahrzeuge ohne Bilder',
            'textAllOK' => 'Alle Fahrzeuge haben Bilder',
            'count' => 0
        );

        $configVehicleWidget['Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis'] = array(
            'link' => 'fahrzeuge.php?parameter=1',
            'image' => 'news/bild1.jpg',
            'linkName' => 'Fahrzeuge ohne Preis',
            'textAllOK' => 'Alle Fahrzeuge haben einen Preis',
            'count' => 0
        );

        $configVehicleWidget['Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern'] = array(
            'link' => 'fahrzeuge.php?parameter=1',
            'image' => 'news/bild1.jpg',
            'linkName' => 'Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern',
            'textAllOK' => 'Keine Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern',
            'count' => 0
        );

        $configVehicleWidget['Herausforderungen'] = array(
            'link' => 'fahrzeuge.php?parameter=1',
            'image' => 'news/bild1.jpg',
            'linkName' => 'Herausforderungen',
            'textAllOK' => 'Keine Herausforderungen',
            'count' => 0
        );

        $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-fahrzeuge']).'</div>
                '.CreateMessage().'
                <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">';
                    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                    {
                        $empty_config=$row['configuration'];
                        if(empty($empty_config )) {
                            $sql="SELECT dashboard_widget.configuration FROM dashboard_widget WHERE Id =1";
                            $sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $myConnection);
                            $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);  
                            $config= unserialize($results['configuration']);                            
                        }
                        else{
                        $config= unserialize($row['configuration']);
                        }

                        foreach($config as $val)
                        {
                            if($val == 'Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder')
                            {

                                $sql='SELECT count( * ) as bilder FROM autodo.amo_bilder_live l LEFT JOIN autodo.afzdaten a ON l.dsnr_afzdaten = a.dsnr WHERE l.dsnr_afzdaten IS NULL';
                                $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
                                $results=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result); 
                                $configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] = $results['bilder'];

                            }
                            else if($val == 'Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis')
                            {
                                $sql='SELECT count(*) as Preis FROM autodo.afzdaten WHERE Preis IS NULL';
                                            $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
                                            $results=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
                                            $configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] = $results['Preis'];
                            }
                            else if($val == 'Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern')
                            {
                                $sql='SELECT count(*) as fehler FROM autodo.afzdaten WHERE fehler IS NULL';
                                $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
                                $results=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
                                $configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] = $results['fehler'];

                            }
                            else if($val == 'Herausforderungen')
                            {
                                $sql='SELECT count(*) as herausforderung FROM autodo.afzdaten WHERE herausforderung IS NULL'; 
                                $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
                                $results=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
                                $configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] = $results['herausforderung'];
                            }                       

                            if($configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] > 0)
                            {
                                $html .= '<a href="'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['link'].'" style="color:red;">'.'<image src="'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['image'].'" width="30" height="25" align="middle">.'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'].' '.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['linkName'].'<br>'.'<br>'.'</a>';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $html .='<span style="color:green;">'.'<image src="'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['image'].'" width="30" height="22" align="middle">.'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['textAllOK'].'<br>'.'<br>'.'</span>';
                            }                           
                    }
                }

                $html .= '              
            </div>          
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
```

Modified Code:

```
foreach($_SESSION['config'] as $val)
                                {
                                    if($val == 'Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder')
                                    {
                                        $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" checked />
                                <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder</label><br>
                 }}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the checkboxes, save their checked/unchecked states? Are you reloading the HTML for the checkboxes after the save/click? What is in the getFahrzeugeWidget() function? What is in the getFahrzeugeWidgetEdit() ?

Comment: yes i want to maintain the state of checkboxes cheked/unchecked for every users after button click. And those fucntions are for filter the options using checkboxes and stored it in the database. It has done successfully but dont know how to maintain the state ?

Comment: You could save it in a cookie in javascript, or in a session variable in php. $_SESSION in php (need to call start_session() at the top).

Comment: Do u have any example for this , and the checkboxes i have checked i am storing those as a array in database and retrieving it later so is it possible to use database to identify which checkboxes is checked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify dashboard.php to save the checkboxes to the session like this:

```
<?php

session_start ();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (isset ($_POST['filterOpts']) && is_array ($_POST['filterOpts']) )
    {
        // save it into the session
        $_SESSION['filterOpts'] = $_POST['filterOpts'];
    }

    echo '{}';
    exit;
}


// ...


// loads the saved values from the session or a new empty array
$filterOpts = (isset ($_SESSION['filterOpts']) && is_array ($_SESSION['filterOpts'])) ? $_SESSION['filterOpts'] : array ();

// retrieves that filteroption (if present = checked)
// returns true or false
function isfo ($name) { global $filterOpts; return in_array ($name, $filterOpts); }


echo '$filterOpts (from session) = <pre>' . htmlspecialchars (print_r ($filterOpts, true)) . '</pre><br/>';

?>


        <table id="FAHRZEUGE" >
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder"  <?php echo isfo ('Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                                <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl Fahrzeuge ohne Bilder</label><br>

                                <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" id="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" value="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis"  <?php echo isfo ('Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                                <label for="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis">Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis</label><br>

                                <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" id="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" value="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern"  <?php echo isfo ('Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                                <label for="Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern">Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern</label><br>

                                <input type="checkbox" name="Herausforderungen" id="Herausforderungen" value="Herausforderungen"  <?php echo isfo ('Herausforderungen') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                                <label for="Herausforderungen">Herausforderungen</label><br><br>                

                        </td>
                    </tr>
<!--
                    <tr><td>
            <input type="button" class="butt-rahmen" id="saveId" value="save" />
                    </td></tr>
-->
                        </table>
```

Saving / loading to a database is very similar to this, but need to replace $_SESSION with your DB.

Comment: i think your solution is right but i am finding it difficult to implementd it ....can i share more code with you... i am not understanding how to do the changes ...

Comment: Sure, which part do you have a problem with ?

Comment: Please check the updated code. My code is very simple. In saveFahrzeugeWidget() fucntion i am filtering the checkbox options and taking it in $param['aktion'] == 'save-widget-vehicle' in php to update my database for every users who have checked the checkboxes. In getFahrzeugeWidget() function i can retrieve and see the filter options using checkboxes checked.Everythng is running fine just need to mantain the state of selected checkboxes....

Comment: As u said now i have put my array into session but just want to know how can i use them now ?

Comment: I think that code is OK for saving the checkboxes. To retrieve them, some SQL like this would work : `SELECT configuration FROM dashboard_widget_users WHERE dsnr_yw_user =".$user_id." AND dsnr_dashboard_widget=1`. Then `unserialize()` the result, and then you have the same array as was saved earlier in the UPDATE. Then check the array with `in_array()` for every checkbox by name, and print "checked" to that checkbox if the name is present in the array.

Comment: The $_SESSION variable can be used like any other variable, the contents of it will be preserved between two page loads. If there is an array in it, `$_SESSION['my_array'] = array ();`, it can be used in the same way as a normal array `$_SESSION['my_array']['a'] = 1; $_SESSION['my_array']['b'] = 2; echo 'a = ' . $_SESSION['my_array']['a'];`

Comment: Please check the update code. I have also added the code for unserialize now tht i did ...yes for retrieving you can see i am doing unserialize to get the result ... But how can i check for checkbox now ? and maintain the state ...i am just missing few line of code for tht :(

Comment: Use `in_array()` to check if the name of the checkbox is present in that array. (I think this line in your code does the same thing: `foreach($config as $val)`, it should already work). If you can't find the bug in that code, try to break it up into smaller pieces and test every piece separately. This is outside of the original question already.

Comment: i mean its running properly and stored in the database as well serialize and unserialize array...there is no bug in that ...my problem is how to maintain state..user know they have checked and retrieve this from checkboxes and if i refresh the page still i will get the filter options ,the only problem is checkbox are not cheked thts it ...only 1 line of code is missing that i dont know how to write...like u have written <input type="checkbox" name="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder"  <?php echo isfo ('Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />

Comment: so i have to change this line according to my code ...thts it ...that only i dont knw ..

Comment: so i think if i put $config into session then i have my unserialize array now just i want to use in my html input type to show which checkbox is checked...plz can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, you only need to change that one line. For example you could change the function "isfo()". You could do a database SELECT in this function. Take the result, check if the $name of the checkbox is there, if it's there , return true, if not , return false. This isn't very efficient, but after it works, you can optimize it. So if you only change the "isfo()" function, you don't need to change that line at all, only the code inside the function.

Comment: hmm but still i am trying to do that but not getting the result :(

Comment: Maybe there is a bug somewhere. You could inspect the DB with a tool like phpMyAdmin or similar, to see the data. And then you can see if the problem is in the code or in the data. I can't help you more with this. Good luck in finding the bug!

Comment: hi just last question if i do something like this then will it work ? please check in the modified updated question at the bottom ...

Comment: No it won't work, consider what your code needs to do.